# Ship python with database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, installation

I want to create a python program with a database (e.g. sqlite) but I don't want the user to install all those dependecies. How can I turn all of this into an only installer (both python with my program and database)?

Comment: "all those dependecies" What dependencies? Python has a [built-in sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) module. If you plan on using another database you should add it to your question.

Comment: I want to ship it to a system without python and sqlite. If I create a python installer for my program, will I be able to create sqlite databases even if the sytem doesn't have it installed?

Comment: There are tons of similar questions on SO. Search for "python to executable"

Comment: Didn't found any similar. Can you point to me one with my problem, please? I need to create a single installer for python and sqlite.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "a single installer for Python and sqlite". There is nothing to install in sqlite. You get it for "free" when installing Python, so you already have a "single installer"

Comment: By single installer I mean and setup.exe (for instance) with python and sqlite. I see but can I still create databases just with this? I thought that it was just a connector to a database and not the whole sqlite itself.

Comment: Oh, I see haha. Thank you very much, @DeepSpace!